# jdbc DB2 queryTimeout not working as expected

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, db2

We are facing issue with the the query timeout property on Db2, it is working when we are running the app in WebSphere, then we moved to Tomcat, this issue was recently caught up by a very long query that hangs very long until timeout after 45 minutes, some pieces of the code we have as below, they haven't been changed since moving to Tomcat:

```
    CallableStatement cs = statementFactory.createCallableStatement(getConnection(), source.getSQL(),
                statementConfig);
    cs.setQueryTimeout(10);
    boolean resultSetAvailable = cs.execute();
    if (resultSetAvailable) {
            resultSet = cs.getResultSet();
        } else {
            resultSet = CallableStatementParamsUtils.checkForOutResultSet(cs, storedProc);
        }
```

- I set up the timeout to be 10 secs, but it didn't timeout at all, anybody knows why?
- The difficulty is Db2 driver is not open source, not able to debug it, How can I solve this issue using Db2?

Comment: Are the properties set and does it match the cases listed here? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjdapi.html

Comment: The IBM db2 jdbc driver supports tracing, to allow problem determination, clearly documented online in Db2 knowledge centre at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html . Verify you are using the *latest* jdbc4 driver always. Get via https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads . Often *other* things have changed, the query itself, the driver version, the Db2-server, the connection mechanism etc.   This is *debugging* not programming.

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for your reply, would you indicate which properties needs to be set which could affact this to be working , the url lists so many of them, it is hard to tell

Comment: There is only a small section on setQueryTimeout

Comment: @mao thank you, you advice on the driver version really helps me, we were not on db2jcc4(it was old db2jcc only), after the upgrade, it seems respecting the querytimeout i set on in the method, just one last thing i want to make sure is, it calls the cancel method to actually cancel the query from server, how would i do that, again, the minified source code is hard to find the cancel method

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the use of a jdbc type 4 driver appeared to help to resolve the issue.

Note that the IBM db2 jdbc driver supports tracing for problem determination as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html).

When dealing with jdbc issues with Db2, it is always helpful to ensure you are using the most recent jdbc driver, available via this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads).

From the comments, the previous jdbc driver was a type-2 driver (which supports query timeouts only in specific configurations as IBM documents in the Db2 knowledge center, the notes are copied below).

The various IBM notes on this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjdapi.html) concerning queryTimeout support in jdbc are essential reading , viz:

> - For DB2 for i, this method (setQueryTimeout) is supported only for a seconds value of 0.
> - For IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 2 connectivity on Db2 for z/OS, Statement.setQueryTimeout is supported only if
>     Connection or DataSource property queryTimeoutInterruptProcessingMode
>     is set to INTERRUPT_PROCESSING_MODE_CLOSE_SOCKET.
> - For IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 2 connectivity on Db2 on Linux, UNIX, and Windows systems, Statement.setQueryTimeout is
>     supported only if Connection or DataSource property
>     queryTimeoutInterruptProcessingMode is set to
>     INTERRUPT_PROCESSING_MODE_STATEMENT_CANCEL.
> - For the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ Version 4.0 and later, Statement.setQueryTimeout is supported for the following
>     methods:
>
>   Statement.execute
>     Statement.executeUpdate
>     Statement.executeQuery
> - Statement.setQueryTimeout is supported for the Statement.executeBatch
>     method only when property queryTimeoutInterruptProcessingMode is set
>     to INTERRUPT_PROCESSING_MODE_CLOSE_SOCKET (2).

Comment: i saw queryTimeoutInterruptProcessingMode before and tried it when i was still on type2 driver last week, it didnt work anyway. but with type4 driver, it seems works anyway no matter if i set the mode or not

Comment: Much depends on the exact *version* of the driver,  regardless of the type. Maintenance of drivers at current levels is key.